# How to save files that doesn't allow user to access the data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay, I have this file data.json to store some persistent data and want to be able to change and store its state even the app terminated. So I want it to be able to store a nested NSArray and doesn't allow user to have access to it.

I think sandbox or supporting file allow users to access the file through itunes. Correct me if I'm wrong. What are the options I have here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add encryption in between while saving array if it is too confidential.or you can go with NSUserDefauls which provide secure storage of data - you can go with this if your data is not heavy.

for more details you can refer my [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550747/how-do-i-save-load-data-in-my-application-using-nscoding/22551513#22551513) answer it is relevant to your problem.

Comment: I have a lot of data though.

Comment: SO you can add encryption/decryption module in you app.